# Manipulando propriedades do áudio em HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, áudio, propriedade

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Meu professor passou um projeto pra fazer um player de áudio, e para isso estava me inspirando no Rdio Music, aí no meu player eu estava planejando quando abrisse um áudio ele carregasse a imagem (correspondente a capa do álbum que já vem embutida no .mp3) no player, porém já pesquisei e não sei como fazer, alguém tem alguma ideia?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar uma lib chamada [jsmediatags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsmediatags), com ela você consegue capturar as informações do arquivo, até mesmo a artwork.

Você usa da seguinte forma, você pode ver outras formas no link que passei e se quiser saber como a lib funciona, recomendo olhar o código no github.

```
var jsmediatags = window.jsmediatags;
jsmediatags.read("http://www.example.com/music-file.mp3", {
  onSuccess: function(tag) {
      console.log(tag);
  },
  onError: function(error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

#### Como extrair uma imagem (capa de álbum) de um arquivo em formato mp3

Geralmente qualquer tipo arquivo digital tem uma assinatura ou uma determinada estrutura que o identifica.

Essa assinatura é sempre válida mesmo quando contida noutro formato incluindo uma imagem dentro de outro tipo de arquivo, neste caso dentro de um arquivo MP3.

ID3v2
Estes metadados, quando presentes, podem conter uma imagem, no formato JPEG ou PNG, indexada a um frame designado como APIC. Quando este está preenchido com uma imagem existe um campo neste frame que indica o seu 'mime type' literal como image/jpeg ou image/png. Os tipos de imagem para ID3v2 estão descritos em https://mutagen-specs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/id3/id3v2.4.0-frames.html#apic .

ID3v1 não dá suporte a qualquer tipo de imagem e outras imagens poderão existir fora do contexto ID3v2 e todas estas estruturas de metadados poderão coexistir, ou não, em simultâneo ou estar completamente ausentes. Na verdade ID3 é um extra formato eventualmente adicionado ao início ou ao final dos dados de áudio não fazendo parte da especificação MP3.

Existem vários editores de metadados ID3v2 para o formato MP3 que adicionam toda a informação necessária incluindo a capa de álbum, como por exemplo https://www.mp3tag.de/en/ .

Na prática não precisa de se preocupar com o identificador APIC nem com o 'mime type' contido nele visto que, por exemplo, ID3v2 não possui offsets fixos apenas limites máximos, bastando para isso ir direto ao assunto e **extrair a imagem** (se existir) **pela sua assinatura**.

O código é válido para os formatos MP3, WMA, FLAC e M4*/Mp4 áudio.

```js
let reader = new FileReader(), file;
reader.onloadend = () => {
player.src = URL.createObjectURL( file );

let picturesindex = [];
let buffer = reader.result;

void new Uint8Array( buffer ).forEach( ( v, i, a ) => 
                                      ( a[i] == 0xFF ||   a[i] == 0x89 ) && 
                                    ( a[i+1] == 0xD8 || a[i+1] == 0x50 ) && 
                                    ( a[i+2] == 0xFF || a[i+2] == 0x4E ) && 
( a[i+3] == 0xE0 || a[i+3] == 0xEE || a[i+3] == 0xE1 || a[i+3] == 0x47 ) && 
picturesindex.push( i ) 
);

let picturescollection = picturesindex.map( ( v ) => 
URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ buffer.slice( v ) ] ) ) 
);

let frontcover = picturescollection[0]? picturescollection.shift( ) : '';
player.poster = frontcover;
player.play();
};

input.onchange = () => 
input.files[0] && reader.readAsArrayBuffer( file = input.files[0] );
```

```html
<video id="player" width="320" height="320" controls></video><br>
<input id="input" type="file" accept="audio/mpeg, audio/mp4, audio/flac, .mp4" />
```

Assinaturas hex e fim de assinatura para os formatos de imagem jpg e png:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ID3 vista no notepad:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou de forma simplificada:

```js
let reader = new FileReader(), file;
reader.onloadend = () => {
player.src = URL.createObjectURL( file );
let picture = reader.result.match(/\x89PNG[\x00-\xFF]+IEND|\xFF\xD8\xFF(?:\xE0|\xEE|\xE1|\xDB)[\x00-\xFF]+\xFF[\xD8-\xD9]{1}/);
player.poster = picture? 'data:;base64,' + btoa( picture ) : '';
player.play();
}

input.onchange = () => 
input.files[0] && reader.readAsBinaryString( file = input.files[0] );
```

```html
<video id="player" width="320" height="320" controls></video><br>
<input id="input" type="file" accept="audio/mpeg, audio/mp4, audio/flac, .mp4" />
```

Comment: Uma baita resposta, pra uma pergunta infeliz :/
Acho que o colega ta com problema na logica la, não no código.